# Search text in different cells and add all results in a cell using Excel

Tags: excel

Let's say I have this list:

Colorado US

Texas US

London UK

Berlin GE

Munich GE

I would like to obtain as result all the cities that end with "US" in a cell, just like this

```
Colorado US Texas US
```

I have applied the formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(find_text;within_text));"Cell_of_CityName";"")
```

This works perfect if I do it cell by cell.

Is there a way to apply this formula to the whole column so that I dont have to do it always cell by cell?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want all results in a single cell? What version of Excel have you got?

Comment: Exactly. I have the Excel 2019 version

Answer (score 1):

in **B1**:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IF(RIGHT(A1:A5,2)="US",A1:A5,""))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh no, I dont know if I am doing something wrong but the formula is not working. Is it maybe something with my Excel version 2019? The result I have got is a blank cell

Comment: @newbie_coder I get a blank also if there are trailing blanks in the data.....check it out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The formula is working now but it's returning me all the cells (range A1:A5) instead of only the "US" cities. You do have as ouput only the US Cities right? That is weird, I am applying the formula just like you did

Comment: I don't know what the problem is.